# How do I link Core frameworks on macOS using Clang?

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clang

I am trying to build a C++ application on macOS with Clang. I am using the CoreAudio API, so I need to link the CoreServices framework. However, I get the following error:

> clang: error: unknown argument: '-framework CoreServices'

Here is my Clang version:

```
clang --version 
clang version 3.9.1 (tags/RELEASE_391/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

These are my linker flags:

```
-framework CoreServices
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe also show your complete `clang` command for compiling; seems like something is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following program code prints out the size occupied by the output devices (this is just to use some functionality from the CoreAudio API):

```
// main.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

#include <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

int
main (void)
{
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress property = {
        kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

    OSStatus status;
    UInt32 size;

    status = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(
            kAudioObjectSystemObject,
            &property,
            0,
            NULL,
            &size);

    printf("status(%d), size: %d\n", status, size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This C++ program can be compiled with:

```
clang -framework CoreServices -framework CoreAudio main.cpp
```

And will produce a `a.out` executable, that you can then call with

```
./a.out
> status(0), siz
```